# MS Word Auto-numbering in headings - how do I remove the indent level

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, numbering

Using MS Word 2016. I want to add numbered headings.

So I select haeding 1 format. I enter "1. My Heading" and hit enter.

I can see that my heading has been converted into a numbered list - I can add/insert/remove other heading 1's so all good...

However it also indents all my headings (same for heading 2, 3, etc...).

how can I get the numbered list, but without the indentations?
I can manually change them by right-click --> paragraph --> Indentation --> left --> set to 0 (was 0.63cm), but that is painful to do it all the time....

**Screen shot**
[image]

Note: I select the font type and then type exactly the text of each line. I do not apply any numbering or indentation.

E.g. select Normal font, type "Normal text", hit enter. Select header1 font, type "1. HEADER 1 with with number at the start" and press enter. That is literally all I am doing. This was in a completely blank new doc.

Comment: This is odd. Would you please provide screenshot?

Comment: @AmeerMousavi updated with picture and comments on how I created this simple file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the **Home** tab, in the **Paragraph** group, click **Multilevel List** > **Define New Multilevel List**.

In the dialog box, click **Set for All Levels**, and set the **Bullet/Number position for first level** field to **0 pt**, and make sure that the **Additional indent for each level** field is also set to **0 pt**.

You can also adjust the **Text position for the first level** value if you think there's too much space between the numbers and the heading text. Or, if you just want a regular space character there instead of a tab space, back in the main dialog box, click **More**, and change the value of the **Follow number with** field from **Tab character** to **Space**.

If you don't want Word to convert numbers that you manually type to autonumbering in the first place, so that you don't have to worry about this issue, click **File** > **Options** > **Proofing**. Click **AutoCorrect Options**, and then, on the **AutoFormat As You Type** tab, clear the **Automatic numbered lists** check box.

Comment: That seemed to do it, thanks. But its a bit long winded :( ... I guess word just thinks it knows best always :o

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a few tries. Right click on `Heading 2` in `Styles` section. Choose `Modify`. Then at the bottom of the dialog click on `Format` button > Choose `Paragraph` > Choose `Tabs` at the bottom. 
Just like in the picture insert a custom number with unit (cm or mm or inch). Click `Set`. Click `OK` twice :)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that - I tried this, set it to 0cm and hit set, ok ok.... nothing happened. I re-applied the format header 2 (it removes the numbering), so I re-try with a new header 2 line with the same result as before : (

Comment: Please set it to 0/7 cm or 0/8 cm and check that. Double check the screen shot.

Comment: Its tells me that 0/8 cm is an invalid tab stop (I did try that last time)...  what is meant to happen?

Comment: Because of your windows units format. Use point or , instead of /

Comment: Ok it accepted the number 0.8 cm. But nothing is changed still...   is this meant to update all my header 2's?. I made a new header 2 line and got the same result : (